# How to deal with two parent divs with children that should appear over the other parent

Tags: html, css

You have two divs, a `header` and a `body`. Sometimes content in `body` is supposed to cover up `header`, and sometimes its vice versa. However, as far as I know, a div (and all its children) with a higher z-index, or with the same z-index but higher up in the code, will always cover up a lower-z-index or lower-positioned div (and all its children).

So how would one deal with, for example, a header with a dropdown menu that drops down into the body, and a pop-up form in the body that's supposed to cover everything, including the header? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.a, .b {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 18px;
}

.a {
    background-color: red;
}

.b {
    background-color: blue;
}

.a span {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
}

.b span {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<span>A</span>
</div>

<div class="b">
<span>B</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.popup {

Position: relative;
Top: -0.5em;
Z-index: 3;
background-color: blue;

}

.dropdown {
Position: absolute;
height: 3em;
Z-index: 2;
Top: 0.75em;

Background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
Some text
<div class="dropdown">
Middle
</div>


</div>

<div>
Some text
</div>


<div class="popup">
TOPPPPPPP
</div>
```

It does not matter the order of the HTML when using z-index, unless 2 elements have the same z-index. Just assign a > z-index to the top most elements.

If you have a popup that you always want to be top most, let it be the first element in the body and assign a z-index of 99.